# Ubuntu does not offers me "install alongside Windows"

Tags: ubiquity, system-installation

Any of the partitions makes in Windows was not recognised by Ubuntu, or Zorin OS, or LinuxMint. It's like a blank hard disc, 250 gb free. I'm a new Linux user, but what confuses me is that I was able to install Ubuntu alongside Windows on my laptop with no problems, but on PC... no way!